# Resize ImageView in run time using a button - Android

Tags: android, resize, runtime, imageview

I am displaying an image using ImageView container. the image needs to be resized when a user enters a specific value and clicks update

resize is just for display, the original resource remains as it is. NO editing, save, etc

xml layout

```
<ImageView 
android:background="@drawable/picture01" 
android:id="@+id/picture01holder" 
android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
</ImageView>
```

main.java

```
final ImageView pic01 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.picture01);
```

now what do i do to dynamically assign this pic01 a size of my choice. just the function, i can implement it inside a button myself. i believe i have to use something like pic01.setLayoutParams but i dont know how to use it.

basically i want to overwrite layout_height="wrap_content" and layout_width="wrap_content"  in .java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change the `Imageview` size by taking `LayoutParams`

```
    final ImageView pic01 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.picture01);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
    pic01.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you have to set the [scale type](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setScaleType%28android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType%29) of the image to [CENTER_INSIDE or CENTER_CROP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) depending on your preferences. You should do this in your onCreate() method.

```
myImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
```

Afterwords you just have to resize the image view in your layout. This will depend on the type of layout you're using. An example for LinearLayout would be:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100,200);
myImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Or you can set the components minimal size:

```
myImageView.setMinimumWidth(200);
myImageView.setMinimumHeight(200);
```

In both cases make sure that the size can be achieved inside the layout. If you have multiple components with smaller weights, the image view may be unable to take up the space you need.

Comment: This is a good answer, but one problem with this answer and all of the other ones currently posted, is that it recommends instantiating a `new LayoutParams`.  The pitfall to this, is that many `ViewGroup`s implement their own `LayoutParams` subclass, and it requires knowledge of the particular `ViewGroup` class in order to know which `LayoutParams` to instantiate.  A simple way around this is to simply retrieve the existing `LayoutParams` instance with `getLayoutParams()`, modify the width and height, and assign it back with `setLayoutParams`.  This will avoid a potential `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 0):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams myParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(yourWidthHere, yourHeightHere);

pic01.setLayoutParams(myParams)
```